# CUDA ERROR : Cannot allocate big buffer for DAG

Tags: mining, cpp-ethereum

[image]

Windows Config
Windows 10
Ram 8GB DDR4
1TB HDD
Vertual Ram set max at 20000mb

Still having CUDA error.

GPU GTX 1060 3 GB x 2
GPU GTX 1060 6 GB x 3

Total 5 GPU

Answer (score 3):

add the command line -eres 0 and it'll run no problem. I think it has something to do with the 3gb cards, not exactly sure what yet.

Edit: Claymores reserves memory for the next epoch (1 more) by default if your mining for days and days and day straight. With that command it reduces it only to the epoch that loads on starting claymores thus I think this is the end of 3GB cards.

Comment: Thnk u sir...By adding command line -eres 0 works for me. Appriciate